# How to prevent giving links by wordpress to images?

Tags: php, wordpress

By default, wordpress link images you enter in the editor. How to turn off this action.

Found this solution but it doesn't work.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'attachment_image_link_remove_filter' );
function attachment_image_link_remove_filter( $content ) {
$content =
preg_replace(
array('{<a(.*?)(wp-att|wp-content\/uploads)[^>]*><img}',
'{ wp-image-[0-9]*» /></a>}'),
array('<img','» />'),
$content
);
return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to your theme's function.php file.

```
function wpb_imagelink_setup() {
    $image_set = get_option( 'image_default_link_type' );

    if ($image_set !== 'none') {
        update_option('image_default_link_type', 'none');
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'wpb_imagelink_setup', 10);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `Insert Media` window, you can select what you'd like your image to be linked to. Simply select **None**.

[image: No link]